# PlayN 1.4 - building Flash war

Tags: playn

I can not maven install Flash from my project.
I have successfully install and run HTML war file,
but when I tried to install Flash project I got errors.
I have seen on other posts that it is a problem
with GWT 2.4 and I have to downgrade to 2.3 in pom file
but it did not help.
The result is that war file is not being properly created.

I got something like this:

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:w
ar (default-war) on project playtest-flash: Error assembling WAR: webxml attribu
te is required (or pre-existing WEB-INF/web.xml if executing in update mode)

Any suggestions?